# ¿Como hacer un DatePicker dentro de un Dialog?

Tags: android, datepicker

Quisiera que alguien me ayudara con esto soy nuevo recién empiezo y he intentado hacer un selector de fecha dentro de mi código , pero no me funciona, este es mi código. Esto me genera una ventana con un formulario donde tengo 2 EditText que deben tomar el valor de una fecha al hacer click en un ImageButton con la ayuda del DatePicker, esto que hice no me da error solo que no me funciona, espero que puedan ayudarme Gracias de antemano

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_adicionar_plan, null);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Adicionar " + getResources().getString(R.string.nav_plan));
    //builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_add);
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //no hacer nada

            BDPlan db = new BDPlan(getContext());
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            EditText editNombreCategoria = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PeditNombreCategoria);
            contentValues.put(db.CN_DENOMINACION, editNombreCategoria.getText().toString());
            CheckBox checkIndividual = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PcheckIndividual);
            if(checkIndividual.isChecked() == true){
                contentValues.put(db.CN_INDIVIDUAL, "1");
            }else {
                contentValues.put(db.CN_INDIVIDUAL, "0");
            }
            CheckBox checkMensual = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PcheckMensual);
            if(checkMensual.isChecked() == true){
                contentValues.put(db.CN_MENSUAL, "1");
            }else {
                contentValues.put(db.CN_MENSUAL, "0");
            }
            CheckBox checkAnual = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PcheckAnual);
            if(checkAnual.isChecked() == true){
                contentValues.put(db.CN_ANUAL, "1");
            }else {
                contentValues.put(db.CN_ANUAL, "0");
            }
            EditText editFechaInicio = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PeditFechaInicio);
            contentValues.put(db.CN_FECHAINICIO, editFechaInicio.getText().toString());
            EditText editFechaFin = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PeditFechaFin);
            contentValues.put(db.CN_FECHAFIN, editFechaFin.getText().toString());
            EditText editDescripcion = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PeditDescripcion);
            contentValues.put(db.CN_DESCRIPCION, editDescripcion.getText().toString());
            db.InsertaP(contentValues);
            //db.ModificarCA(contentValues,String.valueOf(i+1));

            FragmentTransaction transaction;
            transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            PlanFragment fragment = new PlanFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.ContenedorInicio, fragment).commit();


        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.aplicar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //no hacer nada
                    BDPlan db = new BDPlan(getContext());
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    EditText editNombreCategoria = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PeditNombreCategoria);
                    contentValues.put(db.CN_DENOMINACION, editNombreCategoria.getText().toString());
                    CheckBox checkIndividual = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PcheckIndividual);
                    if(checkIndividual.isChecked() == true){
                        contentValues.put(db.CN_INDIVIDUAL, "1");
                    }else {
                        contentValues.put(db.CN_INDIVIDUAL, "0");
                    }
                    CheckBox checkMensual = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PcheckMensual);
                    if(checkMensual.isChecked() == true){
                        contentValues.put(db.CN_MENSUAL, "1");
                    }else {
                        contentValues.put(db.CN_MENSUAL, "0");
                    }
                    CheckBox checkAnual = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PcheckAnual);
                    if(checkAnual.isChecked() == true){
                        contentValues.put(db.CN_ANUAL, "1");
                    }else {
                        contentValues.put(db.CN_ANUAL, "0");
                    }
                    EditText editFechaInicio = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PeditFechaInicio);
                    contentValues.put(db.CN_FECHAINICIO, editFechaInicio.getText().toString());
                    EditText editFechaFin = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PeditFechaFin);
                    contentValues.put(db.CN_FECHAFIN, editFechaFin.getText().toString());
                    EditText editDescripcion = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PeditDescripcion);
                    contentValues.put(db.CN_DESCRIPCION, editDescripcion.getText().toString());
                    db.InsertaP(contentValues);
                    //buscar como no cerrar el dialog
                }
            })
            .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });
```

ImageButton bInicio = (ImageButton) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PbInicio);

```
    bInicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext());

            datePickerDialog.setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day ) {

                    year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    String date = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month) + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
                    EditText editFechaInicio = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.PeditFechaInicio);
                    editFechaInicio.setText(date);
                    datePickerDialog.show();


                }
            });

        }
    });




    builder.setView(dialogView);
    return builder.create();
}
@Override
public void show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    super.show(manager, tag);
}
```

}

Comment: Edita la pregunta y muestra el error que te da log para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toma guiate por esto es uno sencillo

Esto es en la clase main

```
//instancias el date picker que hayas declarado
datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
datePicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.onDateChangedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth + datePicker.getMonth + datePicker.getYear, Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
    }
 });
```

Espero que esto te sirva de guia

Comment: ya puede resolver mi problema gracias de todas formas @AlexRivas

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue mi solución:

```
    bInicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int anno = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    calendario.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    calendario.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    calendario.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    String fechaInicio = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear) + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
                    editText.setText(fechaInicio);
                }
            };
            new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, anno,mes,dia).show();
        }
    });
```